# Python easyprocess import error on Windows 7 as non-admin user

Tags: python, windows, permissions

I am having trouble with an import statement on a python script running as a different user on my computer.

I installed the following on my computer as admin

- Windows x86 ActivePython=2.7.8.10 on Win 7
- pyscreenshot-0.3.4
- PIL-1.1.7

And tested that my script ran fine.  Then I log in as a different user that does not have admin and get a module not found error for easyprocess when trying to import pyscreenshot.  This is what I know:

- I have easyprocess-0.1.9.py2.7.egg in my lib\site-packages directory
- I granted "FULL CONTROL" of the python directory to the non-admin user, just in cases there was a permissions issue
- My py script does not import easyprocess directly, but it is indirectly imported by pyscreenshot.
- My script runs just fine with my other account when I do "runas /user" from the same computer.

Suggestions?

Comment: Since it is a "module not found" rather than a permissions error, check your environment variables, in particular `PYTHONPATH`.  BTW, it is preferable to show the actual error.

Comment: The error is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tools\doScreenshots.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyscreenshot as ss;
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    # The Python Imaging Library.
ImportError: No module named easyprocess

I do not have a PYTHONPATH environment variable and I did a diff of my env vars from the two accounts and found they only differed on items like USERNAME

Comment: OK, check `sys.path` on each.